# Knockout.JS $element data binding variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have an options list element I am building with Knockout.js.  I'm trying to pass the Knockout.js **$element** data binding variable to a Javascript function:

```
<!-- ko with: dataList -->
<div class="container">
<div class="setting topic" data-bind="deselectClick: enabled, css: { disabled: enabled() != true, locked: isLocked() == true }">
    <div class="icon" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: selectedItem().value == '' ? '#1a1a1a' : $parents[1].color }">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="select" data-bind="deselectClick: enabled, click: changeSelect, text: selectedItem().text">Loading...</div>
</div>
<ul class="selectOptions topicSelects" data-bind="foreach: items, style: { display: showOptions() ? 'block' : 'none' }">
    <li data-bind="text: $parent.checkText($element, name), click: $parent.selectChanged">Loading...</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

When I do this, the browser debugger shows an error indicating that **$element** is undefined.   Has anybody seen this condition?  If so, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please try to repro your problem in a jsfiddle! Your code seems fine and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to an old version of KnockoutJS.  $element is a new feature.  I updated the KnockoutJS package to the latest version and it works now.

Comment: Any idea what the old version of $element was...  :(   I have an old giant app still using 2.1 that I can't upgrade.